# Vue JS in HTML Not Recognizing Added Objects and Properties

Tags: javascript, json, data-binding, vue.js, v-for

I have a Vue instance called `myApp`. I have a method in my Vue JS instance that is called loadPlannedAlerts, which is called during `mounted`. It's an AJAX call that first gets JSON data, then adds to it afterwards. The data is a JSON object with key value pairs, that looks something along the lines of `{key: 'value, key2: 'value2}'`.

```
loadPlannedAlerts: function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/get-my-data',
            success: function(data) {
                myApp.messages = JSON.parse(data);
                for (var i = 0; i < myApp.messages.length; i++) {
                    myApp.messages[i].findUser = '';
                }
            }
        });
}
```

In my HTML, I have a `v-for` loop that displays this message data.

```
<div v-for="(message, index) in messages">
    <input type="text" name="user" v-model="message.findUser">
</div>
```

For some reason, I can pull up the added `findUser` key-value in my browser's console, and I can even see it in my browser's dev tools Vue plugin. But The data that is typed into my message box is not binding to each of the `findUser`s.

Is there something I'm missing, or an order of operations that I am overlooking? Anything else that already existed in the data before I added it is binding fine.

**UPDATE**

If I follow Decade Moon's solution for a regular key-value pair, where I don't mutate the component at all, and finish building what it should look like, then assign value to it, then it works fine. If I try to assign a key-value pair where the value is another object with key-value pairs in it, then it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `myApp.messages` declared upfront in the `data` object for that component?

It looks like you're adding a *new* `findUser` property to each message. Vue can't detect this (see [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats)). You should mutate the payload *before* you assign it to the component (at which point Vue will make it reactive).

```
success: function(data) {
  const messages = JSON.parse(data);
  
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    messages[i].findUser = '';
  }

  // Do this last
  myApp.messages = messages;
}
```

Comment: I'm not at work right now so I can't verify if it will work in my situation, but I just created a small test and it did in fact work. I'll be trying this tomorrow and will mark this answer as accepted if it works.

Comment: This solution kind of worked, but also failed when I tried to add a bit more. If I follow this pattern and try to add a key-value pair, it works. If I try to add a key with a value that is an object with key-value pairs, then it doesn't recognize that. Not sure why. If you need clarification on what I mean, I can update my original post.

Comment: That should work. I'll need to see your code and template.